# Make stroke-width of a SVG path depend on position

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have a big (12 MB) SVG file containing many curved paths all having the same stroke width. Now I'd like to transform the stroke-width in a way that it depends on some mathematical function which takes the coordinates of the path segment (or even better: of the actual points on the path segment) as input.

The only way i found so far is to cut the paths in segments using inkscape and then modifying the stroke-width using the etree library for python. But what I really want is continuously decreasing/increasing stroke width like in inkscapes calligraphy tool.